# Monkey patching an imported library to add additional import statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anybody have any guidance on how to dynamically add a few lines of code to a library when calling it?

I know it’s not good practice, but what I would like to do is to enable requests-caching in the fmcapi library for when I use the library for specific functions. Doing this really is just adding:

```
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache(cache_name=‘fmc_cache’, backend=‘sqlite’, expire_after=21600)
```

However, I don’t want to permanently patch the library as this can have undesired effects when performing other functions. I’ve looked at monkey patching, something I’ve not used before but it seems this is more suited to patching classes or methods rather than this use case.

Comment: can you be a little more explicit in your example please, thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `requests_cache` module, but that looks like a global installation - in other words, you can do it in your main program, and any other modules that use `requests` will benefit from it.  No need for monkey-patching.

Comment: jasonharper - that worked a treat, I found this late last night but forgot to update the post, sorry. Now for the python101 question.... I assume that as this worked when you import modules, all classes and methods essentially get inherited into the main program?

Answer (score 0):

## How it works

To explain a little more what's going on under the hood:

- `requests_cache.install_cache()` is actually using monkey patching already.
- Specifically, it patches [requests.Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) with [requests_cache.CachedSession](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html#sessions).
- It looks like the `fmcapi` library calls `requests.get()`
- [Interally, `requests.get()` just calls `requests.Session().request()`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/api.py), so after using `install_cache()`, that call will become `CachedSession.request()`.

## Caching contextmanagers

You can add caching only for specific requests using the `requests_cache.enabled()` contextmanager:

```py
import requests
import requests_cache
from some_other_lib import api_call

# Cached request from a third-party library
with requests_cache.enabled(cache_name='fmc_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=21600):
    api_call()

# Non-cached request
requests.get('https://placeholder.com')
```

Or do the opposite with `requests_cache.disabled()`:

```py
import requests
import requests_cache
from some_other_lib import api_call

requests_cache.install_cache(cache_name='fmc_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=21600):


# Cached request from a third-party library
api_call()

# Non-cached request
with requests_cache.disabled():
    requests.get('https://placeholder.com')
```

See the [User Guide](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html#patching) for more details.

## CachedSession objects

In general, for using requests-cache with other libraries that you don't own, the best case is that the library allows you to provide your own session object, which is cleaner since you can just pass it a `CachedSession` directly instead of monkey-patching it in:

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession
from some_other_lib import api_call

session = CachedSession(cache_name='fmc_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=21600)
api_call(session=session)
```